# how do i set the browser to open localhost for webbrowser?

Tags: python, browser

Below is my code:

```
execfile("main.py");
    url = "localhost:9988";
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url);
```

"main.py" will start the localhost, BUT when i run the script it will not go to webbrowser.open_new_tab(url) because it is stuck in the localhost.

Is there a way to start localhost then open a new tab in a selected browser(ie chrome/firefox) to localhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your main.py won't exit until requested (since it's a server), you will need to create a new process in order to call `webbrowser.open_new_tab`. You can use `subprocess.Popen`, `os.fork` or something similar.

`subprocess.Popen((sys.executable, 'main.py'))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Do it as below with `Popen`. It should work. You have to replace `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` with your own executable.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '8000'])
webbrowser.open_new_tab('localhost:8000')
```

**Execution:**

```
[12:21:49] babil@quad:[/tmp]$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import subprocess
>>> import webbrowser
>>> 
>>> subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '8000'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f09924df210>
>>> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...

>>> webbrowser.open_new_tab('localhost:8000')
True
>>> localhost.localdomain - - [20/Mar/2012 12:22:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Created new window in existing browser session.
localhost.localdomain - - [20/Mar/2012 12:22:29] code 404, message File not found
localhost.localdomain - - [20/Mar/2012 12:22:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

>>>
```